# How to set Terminal paths in OSX 10.8

Tags: java, bash, maven, osx-mavericks, java-home

I have run into a spot of trouble configuring my paths in OSX 10.9.3

To give some context, the issues started when Maven was causing issues referring to my Java version as 1.7, from stackoverflow i took the advice of simply updating my JAVA_PATH

I ran "which java" which gave me:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

SO I ran:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
```

However "man -v" and "java -version" both now complain:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/bin/java//bin/java
```

What I am confused about is that blogs, posts and people are saying check .profile and .bash_profile or .bashrc, only .profile exists on my machine, and nothing seems to take effect there. The only joy I have is setting paths in /etc/paths

So my question has a few part, how do I get my original java path back? Where are these "export" paths set or where can i find this reference to JAVA_HOME and lastly, despite defining "JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java" is it returning the Error that claims the path is "/usr/bin/java//bin/java"

Any help would be good

Comment: If you have to you should set JAVA_HOME to `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` i.e. get the OS to reference the most up-to-date version of java.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME should be set to the name of the directory that contains the bin directory that contains the Java executables (in particular, java itself).

Assuming you do have a /usr/bin/java directory, it probably contains a jre subdirectory that contains the bin directory that contains java and related executables.

So you should probably be setting JAVA_HOME to /usr/bin/java/jre rather than /usr/bin/java.

On the side note: its a bit awkward place to put your java tbh. I would put it in usr/lib/java

Comment: /usr/bin/java is a symlink (most likely) to the java executable (java.exe), so appending a directory to it is likely to fail.